# Windows forms app gives me error when I use Process. Start();

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to open anything with the command Process.Start(); but it keeps giving the error:

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'https://Google.com' with working directory 'C:\Users\Hp\source\repos\bot\bot\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I am not sure why it's using:
C:\Users\Hp\source\repos\XENA\XENA\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows
as the search directory but I have tried this on a windows form app (.Net framework) and it worked fine but now I am just using windows form app and its failing

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("https://www.google.com");
        }
```

Comment: You need to update your post to include some example code. We can't guess what you've written, and need to see what you're doing to help you

Comment: For .NET 6.0 you need to use ProcessStartInfo so you can set its UseShellExecute property to true.

Comment: i used UseShellExecute to true but still get that error

Comment: and i don't need to just open the program, i need to type in the URL too

Answer (score 7):

Hans got it correct but here is a more easy-to-understand code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
                        FileName = "https://www.google.com/,
                        UseShellExecute = true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `Process` class can be used in .NET 6 or above in this manner:

```
Process.Start( new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = @"http://google.com", UseShellExecute = true } );
Process.Start( new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = @"C:\", UseShellExecute = true } );
```

There are some differences between the `Process` class in .NET Framework.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that this fixed my issue. I used your second line. The first solution was a bit unclear. Thanks!

Comment: The second one work perfectly. Many thanks for solution ;-)